# Logistic regression and machine learning how are they related

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression

We were in a meeting discussing hiring a consultant we trust to do machine learning. On colleague piped up that it was just logistic regression and that he would do it

What is machine learning and how does it relate to logistic regression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logistic regression is a supervised machine learning strategy. It classifies input data into two classes

Comment: Hey thanks Mangusta , is that the only or most popular  method used in machine learning?

Comment: neither)) there are tons of machine learning methods each having its own use cases and requirements